# Docker error "Cannot start Docker Compose application" while trying to set up Airflow

Tags: docker, docker-compose, airflow

I'm having some issues while trying to display my local DAGs on Airflow.

I deploy the Airflow with Docker but I'm missing to display the DAGs that I have on my local computer and it's only displaying the "standard" DAGs that came out when I set up the airflow inside the "docker-compose.yaml" file.

the path for my dag/log files is: C:\Users\taz\Documents\workspace (the workspace is the folder where I have the dag and logs folders)

And here is the "docker-compose.yaml"

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  # In order to add custom dependencies or upgrade provider packages you can use your extended image.
  # Comment the image line, place your Dockerfile in the directory where you placed the docker-compose.yaml
  # and uncomment the "build" line below, Then run `docker-compose build` to build the images.
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.2.5}
  # build: .
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'true'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
    _PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS: ${_PIP_ADDITIONAL_REQUIREMENTS:-}
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER: /opt/workspace/dags
  volumes:
    - ./dags: /opt/workspace/dags
    - ./logs: /opt/workspace/logs
    - ./plugins: /opt/workspace/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:0"
  depends_on:
    &airflow-common-depends-on
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:13
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: airflow
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: airflow
      POSTGRES_DB: airflow
    volumes:
      #- postgres-db-volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./:/workspace
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "airflow"]
      interval: 5s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  redis:
    image: redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    restart: always
  airflow-webserver:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: webserver
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:8080/health"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  airflow-scheduler:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: scheduler
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", 'airflow jobs check --job-type SchedulerJob --hostname "$${HOSTNAME}"']
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  airflow-worker:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery worker
    healthcheck:
      test:
        - "CMD-SHELL"
        - 'celery --app airflow.executors.celery_executor.app inspect ping -d "celery@$${HOSTNAME}"'
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
  airflow-init:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: version
    environment:
      <<: *airflow-common-env
      _AIRFLOW_DB_UPGRADE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_CREATE: 'true'
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_USERNAME:-airflow}
      _AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD: ${_AIRFLOW_WWW_USER_PASSWORD:-airflow}
  flower:
    <<: *airflow-common
    command: celery flower
    ports:
      - 5555:5555
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "curl", "--fail", "http://localhost:5555/"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    restart: always
volumes:
  postgres-db-volume:
```

And while trying to run the docker, I got the error

**Cannot start Docker Compose application. Reason: Error invoking remote method 'compose-action': Error: Command failed: docker compose --file "docker-compose.yaml" --project-name "workspace" --project-directory "C:\Users\taz\Documents\workspace" up -d services.airflow-webserver.volumes.0 type is required**

Answer (score 0):

You havent set the environment variable of **$AIRFLOW_HOME** which is why it dosent show your dags, as this variable is an home/ directory to airflow and your **volume/mnt** is kind of path to dags

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Kaolin, so, on that case, I would add "AIRFLOW_HOME: /mnt/c/Users/taz/Documents/workspace" on the environment part, right?

Comment: Well the path depends on you what you like , But default airflow home is ~/airflow. Also sharing a link you can take help from

[https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.0/start.html]

Comment: Btw just a Tip if you want to remove the examples, DO this   AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'

Comment: thanks for your help @Kaolin, still working on the airflow_home part, haven't found the best "way" to write the path to find my data

Comment: try this 



    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_FOLDER: /opt/airflow/dags

Comment: Already addedd but I got an error "Cannot start Docker Compose application. Reason: Error invoking remote method 'compose-action': Error: Command failed: docker compose --file "docker-compose.yaml" --project-name "workspace" --project-directory "C:\Users\taz\Documents\workspace" up -d services.airflow-init.volumes.0 type is required"

Comment: i think you are giving wrong command try to build the images first which is  " docker build ." and then after that run "docker-compose up "

Comment: Got that, I'm gonna check out this part, thanks a lot